# Ubuntu allow www-data to write to new files

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, ubuntu

How to allow www-data group on Ubuntu to write into new just created files by www-data?

I'm using a PHP script and it creates a file (owner is www-data), and after that  I need to write to this file. But it failed, I think because www-date hasn't write access to new file.

And provide all access to all users to the directory where this file need to  be created but it doesn't work because new file is created by www-data so it doesn't have permission to write.

My script:

```
crontab -l > file && echo \"test\" >> file
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the directory you are writing to allows for www-data to write to it.  Typically, you will want to put that directory in a place that is away from other files etc...

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data <DIRNAME>
sudo chmod g+w <DIRNAME>
```

should do the trick for you.

If the filename you are writing to already exists, the same commands above, applied to the file itself, should work as well.  Typically, if the PHP script you wrote is creating the file, and failing, it's due to the parent directory permissions.  For clarity - the commands that would adjust the file permissions and ownership.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data <FILENAME>
sudo chmod g+w <FILENAME>
```

Finally, should you not be able to adjust the ownership of either the directory or the file, you can assign other or all access. But I would highly recommend NOT doing this for various scary security reasons.